# How to write an image file on server?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, image-manipulation

I have a silverlight 3 app using webservices, which uploads an image to server. Then, on server, I resize this image (using EmguCV) and I want to save this image on the server filesystem. The resulting image is created with the size (500px max in one dimension) and saved to 'C:\ ...". This is all working well when debugging in asp dev server. On iis this is not working properly. Probably, this has to do with permissions and web.config, but I can't find the answer.  Any help would be great.

regards

Answer (score 1):

When you run IIS, you are running as a different user that might not have permission.  It depends on the version of IIS, but it's usually ASPNET.  Information here on how to change it if you want.

http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount

If you are using impersonation, then it would be trying to write as the impersonated user.

If you leave it ASPNET (you probably should) -- then just give it permission to write to this directory.